# How can I do a if else statement on a length validation in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

Basically I need one max length validation of 65000 if `key_type` is `4` and another of 255 if its anything else.

It might seem stupid to have this but its needed for a certain situation. I cant seem to get anything to work.

I tried this

```
  validates :value, length: { maximum: 65000, if: 'key_type == 4' }, length: { maximum: 255, if: 'key_type != 4' }, uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key], if: 'key_type == 2'  }
```

But it just seems to have the second `:length` overwrite the first. And a similar thing happens below with the first `maximum: 65000` being ignored completely

```
  validates :value, length: { maximum: 65000, if: 'key_type == 4', maximum: 255, if: 'key_type != 4' }, uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key], if: 'key_type == 2'  }
```

And this also doesnt work

```
if :key_type == 4
 validates :value, length: { maximum: 65000 }, uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key], if: 'key_type == 2'  }
else
  validates :value, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key], if: 'key_type == 2'  }
end
```

I'm not the best in rails but there has to be a way to have this work in the model right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is by passing a `Proc` object condition to the validation method, such as:

```
validates :value,
  length: { maximum: 65000 },
  uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key] },
  if: ->{ key_type == 4 }

validates :value,
  length: { maximum: 255 },
  uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key] },
  if: ->{ key_type != 4 }
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless) for the documentation on this.

If this becomes too cumbersome, you could consider refactoring into custom validation methods/classes. For example, an alternative approach would be to split the validation into two parts:

```
validates :value,
  uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key] }

validate :value_length

def value_length
  if key_type == 4
    errors.add(:value, 'is too long') if value.length > 65000
  else
    errors.add(:value, 'is too long') if value.length > 255
  end
end
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) for documentation on custom validation methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the validations one after another:

```
validates :value, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: [:category_item_id, :key] }, if: 'key_type == 2'
validates :value, length: { maximum: 65000 }, if: 'key_type == 4'
validates :value, length: { maximum: 255 }, unless: 'key_type == 4'
```